# I'm getting an error message and not sure why "PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'Maze.png'"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

**SOLVED!**

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

---

**Post:**

I've been trying to create a program which creates a perfect maze and outputs a .png file. I want this file to then be outputted in a GUI. but receive this message *PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'Maze.png'*

All Relevant Code:

**Maze_Prep.py**

```
import random

class Cell:
    
    wall_pairs = {'N': 'S', 'S': 'N', 'E': 'W', 'W': 'E'}
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.walls = {'N': True, 'S': True, 'E': True, 'W': True}

    def has_all_walls(self):
        return all(self.walls.values())

    def knock_down_wall(self, other, wall):
        self.walls[wall] = False
        other.walls[Cell.wall_pairs[wall]] = False

class Maze:

    def __init__(self, nx, ny, ix=0, iy=0):
        self.nx, self.ny = nx, ny
        self.ix, self.iy = ix, iy
        self.maze_map = [[Cell(x, y) for y in range(ny)] for x in range(nx)]
        self.add_begin_end = False

    def cell_at(self, x, y):
        return self.maze_map[x][y]

    def write_svg(self, filename):
        aspect_ratio = self.nx / self.ny
        padding = 100
        height = 250
        width = int(height * aspect_ratio)
        scy, scx = height / self.ny, width / self.nx
        
        def write_wall(ww_f, ww_x1, ww_y1, ww_x2, ww_y2):
            print('<line x1="{}" y1="{}" x2="{}" y2="{}"/>'
                  .format(ww_x1, ww_y1, ww_x2, ww_y2), file=ww_f)

        def add_cell_rect(f, x, y, colour):
            pad = 5
            print(f'<rect x="{scx*x+pad}" y="{scy*y+pad}" width="{scx-2*pad}"'
                  f' height="{scy-2*pad}" style="fill:{colour}" />', file=f) 

        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', file=f)
            print('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"', file=f)
            print('    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"', file=f)
            print('    width="{:d}" height="{:d}" style="background-color:white" viewBox="{} {} {} {}">'
                  .format(width + 2 * padding, height + 2 * padding,
                          -padding, -padding, width + 2 * padding, height + 2 * padding),
                  file=f)
            print('<defs>\n<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[', file=f)
            print('line {', file=f)
            print('    stroke: #000000;\n    stroke-linecap: square;', file=f)
            print('    stroke-width: 10;\n}', file=f)
            print(']]></style>\n</defs>', file=f)

            for x in range(self.nx):
                for y in range(self.ny):
                    if self.cell_at(x, y).walls['S']:
                        x1, y1, x2, y2 = x * scx, (y + 1) * scy, (x + 1) * scx, (y + 1) * scy
                        write_wall(f, x1, y1, x2, y2)
                    if self.cell_at(x, y).walls['E']:
                        x1, y1, x2, y2 = (x + 1) * scx, y * scy, (x + 1) * scx, (y + 1) * scy
                        write_wall(f, x1, y1, x2, y2)

            print('<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{}" y2="0"/>'.format(width), file=f)
            print('<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="{}"/>'.format(height), file=f)

            if self.add_begin_end:
                add_cell_rect(f, 0, -1, 'green')
                add_cell_rect(f, self.nx - 1, self.ny, 'red')

            print('</svg>', file=f)

    def find_valid_neighbours(self, cell):
        delta = [('W', (-1, 0)),
                 ('E', (1, 0)),
                 ('S', (0, 1)),
                 ('N', (0, -1))]
        neighbours = []
        for direction, (dx, dy) in delta:
            x2, y2 = cell.x + dx, cell.y + dy
            if (0 <= x2 < self.nx) and (0 <= y2 < self.ny):
                neighbour = self.cell_at(x2, y2)
                if neighbour.has_all_walls():
                    neighbours.append((direction, neighbour))
        return neighbours

    def make_maze(self):
        n = self.nx * self.ny
        cell_stack = []
        current_cell = self.cell_at(self.ix, self.iy)

        nv = 1
        while nv < n:
            neighbours = self.find_valid_neighbours(current_cell)
            if not neighbours:

                current_cell = cell_stack.pop()
                continue

            direction, next_cell = random.choice(neighbours)
            current_cell.knock_down_wall(next_cell, direction)
            cell_stack.append(current_cell)
            current_cell = next_cell
            nv += 1
```

**Maze.py**

```
from Maze_Prep import Maze
import time
import aspose.words as aw
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

# Maze dimensions (ncols, nrows)
nx, ny = 10, 10
# Maze entry position
ix, iy = 0, 0

maze = Maze(nx, ny, ix, iy)
maze.add_begin_end = True
maze.make_maze()

print('Maze Loaded!')

maze.write_svg('Maze.svg')

# Converts .svg to .png
doc = aw.Document()
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

shape = builder.insert_image("Maze.svg")
shape.image_data.save("Maze.png")
```

**Maze_GUI.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Maze")


myImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Maze.png'))
myLabel = Label(image=myImg)
myLabel.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Tried running a .png downloaded from the web and it worked fine. So not sure why it wont work. Try running it yourselves.

Comment: 1. can you open the png file (without the GUI),   2. is the png file in the folder where the `maze_gui.py` file is ?

Comment: Please make your question [mcve]. Is it about a Maze library? Or writing an SVG by hand? Or about **PIL** opening a PNG? Or about **tkinter**?

Comment: "Maze.png" may be a SVG file actually.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, don't just put *SOLVED!* in the question, post an answer and accept it.